# I have an error message if I disable htaccess files on Drupal 8

Tags: security, apache-2.4, performance, virtualhost, .htaccess

I have an LAMP server for my Drupal 8 site.

I want to disable htaccess files to have a better server.

I followed the following tutorial :

https://www.vincentliefooghe.net/content/virtualhost-apache-pour-drupal

But now when I load a page of my site, I have a blank page with the following message :

```
handle($request); $response->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

My server `/etc/apache2/sites-available/www-domaine-com-le-ssl.conf` :

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
   <VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerAdmin contact@domaine.com
      ServerName domaine.com
      ServerAlias www.domaine.com
      Protocols h2 http/1.1
      DocumentRoot /var/www/www-domaine-com/web/

      <Directory /var/www/www-domaine-com/web>
         Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride None
         Require all granted

         Include /var/www/www-domaine-com/web/.htaccess
         Include /var/www/www-domaine-com/web/sites/default/files/.htaccess
      </Directory>

      <FilesMatch \.php$>
         SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
      </FilesMatch>

      <Proxy "fcgi://localhost/" enablereuse=on flushpackets=on max=10>
      </Proxy>

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

      Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
      SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domaine.com/fullchain.pem
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domaine.com/privkey.pem

      Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
      Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
      Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
      Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
      Header always set X-Download-Options "noopen"
      Header always set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"
      Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src https: data: wss: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; base-uri 'self';"
      Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
   </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: +1 for disabling .htaccess files -  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/htaccess.html#when

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `.htaccess` file modifies the behavior of the apache webserver in the directory it is placed in (and any subdirectories of that directory).

Without knowing the contents of the two separate .htaccess files I would expect that instead of a single directory block you need two directory blocks as the second .htaccess is not supposed to be applied to the contents of  /var/www/www-domaine-com/web and you need something along the lines of :

```
  <Directory /var/www/www-domaine-com/web>
     ...
     Include /var/www/www-domaine-com/web/.htaccess

  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/www-domaine-com/web/sites/default/files>
     ...
     Include /var/www/www-domaine-com/web/.htaccess
     Include /var/www/www-domaine-com/web/sites/default/files/.htaccess
  </Directory>
```